# purchase notebooks on sell at price some number

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> In a certain shop, notebooks that normally sell for 59 cents each
>   are on sale at 2 for 99 cents. How much can be saved by purchasing
>   10 dollars of these notebooks at the sale price?

I don't understand:

- either notebooks normally sell 59 cents, each one is sold at 2 (amount) for 99 cents,
- or if we sell 2 of them, price for them is 99 cents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Previously, $1$ notebook costs $59$ cents. Now, $2$ notebooks cost $99$ cents together. That means if we buy $10$ notebooks now, we spend $5$ times of $99$ cents.

Comment: thank you very much,i have undertsood now,so it means saved would be 590-495?